# Derivatives of little o.

Tags: calculus

Is it true that $$\left.\frac{d^{k}o(x^i)}{dx^k}\right|_{x=0}=0$$ for every $i=0,1,\ldots,k-1?$

Remember that:

1. $f(x)\in o(x^i)$ if $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^i}=0$;
2. $\left.\dfrac{d^{k}o(x^i)}{dx^k}\right|_{x=0}=\left.\left\{\dfrac{d^{k}f(x)}{dx^k}\right|_{x=0}:f(x)\in o(x^i) \right\}.$

Comment: Your 1. describes $o(g)$ as $x\to \infty$. That is clearly without influence on the derivatives at $0$. You probably want "... for every $0 < x < x_0$" or something along these lines. The answer is "no" anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I have written it again.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x) = x^2\sin\frac 1x$. Clearly, $f(x) = o(x)$ but
$$
f'(x) = x^2 \times -\frac 1{x^2} \cos\frac 1x + 2x\sin\frac 1x = -\cos\frac 1x +o(x)
$$
do not converge to $0$.

Comment: I agree, but in your case $i=1$ so we can only hope for $k=0,$ i.e. $f(x)=o(x).$ In order to have $f'(x)=o(x),$ I am requiring $f(x)=o(x^2).$

Comment: @user39115 for a generic example, you can look what $x^n\sin\frac 1x$ gives.

Comment: $2x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is not a $o(x)$ function, in this case the limit is taken as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt of answer. If $f(x)=o(x^n)$ then 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=0,
$$
also we have 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{d f(x)}{dx}}{nx^{n-1}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{d^{2} f(x)}{dx^2}}{n(n-1)x^{n-2}}=\cdots=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{d^{n} f(x)}{dx}}{n!},
$$
therefore 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{d^{k} f(x)}{dx^k}=0 \mbox{ for every $k=0,1,\ldots,n$.}
$$

This arguments requires that $\frac{d^{k} f(x)}{dx^k}$ exists for every $k=0,1,\ldots,n.$

So my answer is:

For $i\geq k$

$$ \left\{\frac{d^{k}f(x)}{dx^k}|_{x=0}: f(x)=o(x^i), \exists \frac{d^{k}f(x)}{dx^k}|_{x=0} \mbox{ and } \frac{d^{k}f(x)}{dx^k} \mbox{ is continuous at }0 \right\}=\{0\}.$$